# What is $\mathtt{7.6923077e+13}$ in pure numbers?

Tags: notation

I don't know how to convert $\mathtt{7.6923077e+13}$ into pure numbers without $\mathtt{e+}$.

Comment: e+x is short hand notation for $\times 10^{x}$, I believe. So it's just $7.6923077 \times 10^{13}$

Comment: "e+13" means "times $10^{13}$. Google "scientific notation".

Comment: This comes from the Olden Days when computer printers could not write exponents and such things.

Answer (score 3):

$$7.6923077e+13$$
$$76.923077e+12$$
$$769.23077e+11$$
$$7692.3077e+10$$
$$76923.077e+9$$
$$769230.77e+8$$
$$7692307.7e+7$$
$$76923077.e+6$$
$$769230770.e+5$$
$$7692307700.e+4$$
$$76923077000.e+3$$
$$769230770000.e+2$$
$$7692307700000.e+1$$
$$76923077000000.e+0$$

Answer (score 2):

Move the decimal dot 13 positions to the right:
\begin{align}7.6923077\text{e+}13&=7.692307700000000\!\dots\text{e+}13=76923077000000.00\!\dots\\&=76,\!923,\!077,\!000,\!000
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$\mathtt{e+x}$ and $\mathtt{e-x}$ are often used to represent $10^x$ and  $10^{-x}$. If you are familiar with Computer Science, these are used in representing numbers while using Floating type modifiers.

For your number $\mathtt{7.6923077e+13}$, I would say that it just represent $7.6923077 \cdot 10^{+13}$.
I think moving the dots to right and decreasing the power is not a big deal now.